# jpGraph - How to send image through POST call

Tags: php, jquery

On client side there is jQuery script sending POST request to example.php.

```
$.post('example.php', function(data) {
    var $newImg = $('<img src="' + data + '"/>');
    $('#placeholder').html($newImg);
});
```

Example PHP should return image data encoded with base64_encode, but something goes wrong. Here is part of example.php:

```
$contentType = 'image/png';
$gdImgHandler = $graph->Stroke(_IMG_HANDLER);
$image_data = $graph->img->Stream();

$str = "data:$contentType;base64," . base64_encode($image_data);
echo $str;
exit;
```

**Edit:** On client side, instead of image there is a lot of characters:
[image]

I couldn't imagine what is problem here. I already did sending image data through POST but with other library. Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT2** It looks like returned image data has > in it so it's divided into image + custom tag. Look this:
[image]
**EDIT3:** I'am sorry, I made mistake. I'am researching chart libraries, and I was wrong because I posted in title that have problem with PHPlot, actually I have problem with jpGraph chart library. Again, sorry for this. I still have solution but for jpGraph.

**EDIT4:** If I try Lightness Races in Orbit's code:

```
$contentType = 'image/png';
$gdImgHandler = $graph->Stroke(_IMG_HANDLER);

ob_start();                        // start buffering
$graph->img->Stream();             // print data to buffer
$image_data = ob_get_contents();   // retrieve buffer contents
ob_end_clean();                    // stop buffer

echo "data:$contentType;base64;" . base64_encode($image_data);
```

I get this in browser:
[image]

In the firebug I see this:
[image]

Comment: `but something goes wrong` how do you see it?

Comment: Try echoing `$image_data` whether it contains an image. You could do better when setting headers to Content-Type:image/png and than echoing the `$image_data` to see whether it is a valid image. Or, what exactly is wrong here? Does PHP output something or not? Does <img> write correctly to the webpage or not? I do not see any problem here (except for the `$graph` object I do not know)...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach screenshot. See my edit.

Comment: @ИванБишевац  Are you able to check with FireBug or Developer Tools in Chrome how the inserted img tag looks in the DOM structure of the page and what the data transferred from the server looks like? Or, may be, you have a link to the page with a problem.

Comment: I do not think it's caused by library, nor by jQuery. I do not use $.post, instead I use $.ajax that has more controll abilities during AJAX request. Also I'd never used <img> with base64_encoded image data - only read about it and I guess Your syntax is correct.

Try this: `$str = "...". chunk_split(base64_encode($image_data));`

Comment: @Cheery, I added edit to question. Look at screenshot.

Comment: @shadyyx, `$str = "...". chunk_split(base64_encode($image_data));` doesn't help.

Comment: @ИванБишевац: Of course it is not `$str = '...'`. Whole line is: `$str = "data:$contentType;base64," . chunk_split(base64_encode($image_data));` (I was lazy to type it all).

Comment: @shadyyx, I tried this, but didn't helped, same thing.

Comment: @ИванБишевац  It looks like you forgot to encode it with Base64. The data string has symbols which not supposed to be in Base64 encoding. And, specifically, it does not have `data` and other section. Are you sure you get from the correct script? Or the Stream() functions outputs the image file content directly, not to the  $image_data variable.

Comment: @Cheery: How is invoking `base64_encode` "[forgetting] to encode it with Base64"? Also, no need to write the same thing as both a comment and an answer; in fact, please _don't_ do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I gave him a comment and than decided to give a full explanation of what is happening there. The space provided by the comments is not enough for the whole message in general.

Comment: @ИванБишевац check updated code in my answer. It will help you.

Comment: @ИванБишевац Anyway, you do not need Stream() when you are calling Stroke() without arguments. It will output image and you do not use $gdImgHandler later.

Comment: Next time if you see a problem with an answer, please _comment on that answer_, instead of making edit after edit to your question. It's been almost three years and I'm only just now seeing it.

Answer (score 4):

#### In your Javascript

Firstly, you're not HTML-escaping `data`. Clearly something — probably a `/` character, which is index 63 in the base-64 system — is closing the `img` tag, which is why you see so much of the data spill out into the surrounding text.

Use a technique that doesn't require you to, by not writing HTML yourself but manipulating the DOM directly:

```
$.post('example.php', function(data) {
    var $newImg = $('<img />');
    $newImg.attr('src', data);   // <----- just string, not HTML, input
    $('#placeholder').html($newImg);
});
```

---

#### In your PHP

Additionally, as @Cheeky points out and as [the manual's examples](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch05s05.html) demonstrate:

```
 $image_data = $graph->img->Stream();
 // ^                          ^
 // |                          + outputs image data
 // + nothing assigned
```

Your use of `Stroke` is not needed; that would allow you to write to a file or to get the GD handle, but since neither GD nor jpGraph allow to you obtain the image buffer directly, this is no use to you.

So, you have to write a workaround.

You could go directly:

```
<?php
$contentType = 'image/png';
$gdImgHandler = $graph->Stroke(_IMG_HANDLER);

echo "data:$contentType;base64,";  // print prefix
$graph->img->Stream();             // print data
?>
```

The problem with this, though, is that your data is no longer base-64 encoded. PHP's [output buffering features](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) will resolve this:

```
<?php
$contentType = 'image/png';
$gdImgHandler = $graph->Stroke(_IMG_HANDLER);

ob_start();                        // start buffering
$graph->img->Stream();             // print data to buffer
$image_data = ob_get_contents();   // retrieve buffer contents
ob_end_clean();                    // stop buffer

echo "data:$contentType;base64," . base64_encode($image_data);
?>
```

A bit verbose, but jpGraph doesn't appear to have a built-in way around that.

Comment: [@Aparna](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3484053/aparna) Sorry that reviewers rejected your correct edit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to encode it with Base64. The data string has symbols which not supposed to be in Base64 encoding. And, specifically, it does not have `data` and other sections. Are you sure you get it from the correct script? **Or the Stream() function outputs the image file content directly into the stdout, not to the  $image_data variable.**

Try to use http://phplot.sourceforge.net/phplotdocs/EncodeImage.html

```
$image_data = $graph->EncodeImage('base64');
```

You do not need `base64_encode` after that.

ps: downvoter - you DO NOT see obvious thing here, think more about what I wrote above and in comments. His Stream() (or something else) outputs the content of the PNG file back to the browser! **That is why `<img src='.PNG..` shows the header of PNG file and its binary content**.

pps: If you are talking about jGraph then you code should look like (I do not see required function in the API, only examples allowing to save image to file);

```
$contentType = 'image/png';
ob_start();
$graph->Stroke();
$image_data = ob_get_clean();

$str = "data:$contentType;base64," . base64_encode($image_data);
echo $str;
exit;
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  LOOK CAREFULLY BEFORE YOU DOWNVOTE!!! His php script outputs content of PNG file directly, no to the $image_data variable. You can see it by the PNG in the beginning of the inserted data into the IMG tag, which is a PNG file header!

Comment: Where does it do that? He writes `$image_data = $graph->img->Stream();`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do not care what he does, I see how the data inserted into the IMG tag looks like. Which tells me that this is a content if the image file, not the string he was tried to prepare!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  You do not see obvious things. If I'll do (I'm trying to give you the idea of what is happening here) `$image_data = echo "Something"; $str = "base64," . base64_encode($image_data);
echo $str;` What you will get into the javascript variable after AJAX?

Comment: So `$graph->img->Stream()` outputs, does it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  it looks like that. Or something else - I didn't check the API of this class. I gave a link to the OP with description of the function returning content of the image without output.

Comment: OK, I've confirmed that. I don't see how it's all that "obvious", frankly, and my point about HTML escaping stands: it's the _only_ reason you're actually seeing data on the screen. Otherwise your [invalid] data would still just be tied up inside the image. _That's_ the obvious part.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  `I don't see how it's all that "obvious"` it is obvious from the data inserted into the page, that is why I asked to show what OP has there. The data is, again obviously, not base64 encoded, but binary, and is missing 'data' string in the beginning of the 'src'. Its replacement by the 'PNG' in the first bytes tells that it is a binary content of the image, which was sent to output before `echo $str;`. You do not have to be genius to understand that.

Comment: You seem to be forgetting what's happening to the data. It's being written into an `<img>` tag. _The only reason you see it because it contains a `/`._ That means the fact you can't see `data:` is not proof of anything whatsoever; only that, if present, it's found _before_ the `/` that breaks the tag.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  EDIT2 shows an image of the DOM structure of the page with inserted data. I do not care whether it has there / or not. It should have, at least, closing " and > symbols (which are not a part of base64) in order to see anything on the page. BUT it is OBVIOUS that output contains binary symbols, which are not supposed to be after base64.

Comment: I long ago conceded that the data is not base-64, as indicated in an hours-old edit in my answer. _But_ the HTML escaping _must_ be missing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  That `var $newImg = $('<img src="' + data + '"/>');` will not break without escaping! It only happened due to the binary data! `var str = 'A have some text here with / in it. Look, there is no problem with it!';
$('body').append($('<input style="width:100%" value="'+str+'" />'));`

Comment: @Cheery, your last code doesn't work, it prints gibberfish text like before.

Comment: @ИванБишевац Could you show the whole php script in that case? Not just a portion of it. You may initiate output somewhere else before this part of the script.

Comment: @ИванБишевац There was a typo here `$image_data = ob_get_clean();` If image is not shown, it means that the structural data of the image file is damaged. Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: I see you've nicked my output buffering idea! We're even ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  You are a very strange person. I wrote it before you even read comments to your answer. I do not like the way you use other answers in your own.

Comment: @Cheery: No, I wrote it first. Look at the timestamps in the edit histories. However, I like how you've been here for all of ten days and are already accusing site regulars of being "very strange". Awesome!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Because you are unethical in general. About the time stamps... Compare these two screenshots. Take into account the time shown there. http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/735/clipboard01vd.jpg  and http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/606/clipboard02sv.jpg

Comment: @Cheery: Hmm, seems your edit _was_ earlier than I'd realised. However, I didn't see it before I posted my edit. Instead of leaping to the conclusion that I've accrued almost 50k by being "unethical in general", you're just going to have to take my word for it. This conversation is over now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I do not care about the reputation and the person flaunting with some points.. call him any way you want. I just do not want to talk to you anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I did what Lightness said, but I had to change the following for it to work:

`data:$contentType;base64;` to `data:$contentType;base64,`

That is, a comma instead of a semicolon.

Comment: This is not an answer. The original Poster already knew the correct syntax for this. This should go into a comment to Lightness' answer.

Comment: I wish somebody had pinged me about this! Almost two years later, I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This returns a GD resource:

```
$gdImgHandler = $graph->Stroke(_IMG_HANDLER);
```

extend by:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($gdImgHandler);
$image_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $str = "data:$contentType;base64," . base64_encode($image_data);
```

I use this code when I'm caching large graphs for statistics base64 encoded in memcached, so I know it's working. If you don't use PNG, replace `imagepng()` by `imagejpeg()` or something.